# issue with Playerprefs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a "datapack" hidden in each of my levels, the system remembers per level if the artifact has been taken and if so it disables the artifact when a player replays it but i also want to keep track of the total amount taken, the system almost works there's just 1 small issue:
When i finish the level with the first datapack, in the menu it says: 1, this is correct.
but when i do it with the 2nd, it says 3, with the 3rd it says 4, 4th says 5 etc
i don't understand why and thus can't fix it
here's the code:

```
function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider) {
    if(other.CompareTag("DataPacket")){
    pickedUpDataPacket = 1; 
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
    gameObject.Find("DatapackFound").guiText.enabled = true;
    yield WaitForSeconds (1.5);
    gameObject.Find("DatapackFound").guiText.enabled = false;
    }
    if(other.CompareTag("Finish") && pickedUpDataPacket == 1){
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("DataPackLevel" + levelindex.ToString(), 1);
    //if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("totalDatapacks")){
    //PlayerPrefs.SetInt("totalDatapacks", 1);
    //} else {
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("totalDatapacks", (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("totalDatapacks")+1));
    } 
    }
//}
```

i already commented a part out, i believe this was also part of the issue.

and part of a 2nd script:

```
if(datapacktotal){
    if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("totalDatapacks") > 0){
        findText.text = "Collected:" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("totalDatapacks");
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the described behaviour it seems that, in some occasions, the collision **is triggered multiple times**, before the datapack is being destroied. As in level 2, where the counter passes from 1 to 3.

My though is that your collider has **multiple contact points**, so that - if you touches *n* of them - the collision is triggered *n* times.

I would try a simple experiment, just use a flag to determine if that's the first time you "touch" the collider; then, you'll update the PlayerPref just in that case:

```
function OnTriggerEnter (other : Colliderstrong text){
   if (collisionAlreadyConsidered) return;
   collisionAlreadyConsidered = true;
   // your code here...
}

function Update(){
   collisionAlreadyConsidered = false;
}
```

, where collisionAlreadyConsidered is a global variable.